# Blue pointer in Google Maps isn't moving, but stays still

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Redmi Note 4 on Android 5.0 Lollipop. When I enter into the navigation mode of Google Maps, the pointer doesn't move at all. But when I exit the navigation mode, the pointer moves on the map.

The GPS is working finely, and the map is getting the info but doesn't work for the navigation mode only.

What is the reason, how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any vpn service/ad blocker running? I had similar issue, it was solved after I deactivated th ad blocker.